# can't change auth authenticate method

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I have 2 authenticate method for `Auth` component. `Default` and `Special`.
First method is for all users, and `Special` for my friends...

I want to change authenticate method to `Special` when posted `role` is equal to `2`..
So I put this in my `UsersController` `login` method:

```
if($this->request->data['role'] == 2){
    $this->Auth->authenticate = 'Special';
    echo 'Method changed!';
}
if($this->Auth->login()){
    ......
}
```

and if `AppController`, where I set `$components`:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session',
    'Auth' => array('authenticate' => 'Default'));
```

but, when I send a form with `role=2`, it prints `Method changed` but won't change the authenticate method and use `Default` method..

Have I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've a simplier solution :

In your controller, define your new authenticate array :

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array(
    'userModel' => 'User',
    'fields' => array('username' => 'login', 'password' => 'password'),
));
```

Then to make your changes effective in your application, simply write :

```
$this->Auth->constructAuthenticate();
```

That's all :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and I solved it by defining the same variable in the `beforeFilter` action of the `AppController`:

```
function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();

    // Pass settings in
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array(
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
    ));

    ...

}
```

So in your case I would do the following in the AppController:

```
function beforeFilter() {

    parent::beforeFilter();

    if($this->request->data['role'] == 2){
        $this->Auth->authenticate = 'Special';
        echo 'Method changed!';
    } else {
        $this->Auth->authenticate = 'Default';
    }

    ...

}
```

... and in the components declaration only write:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Auth');
```